# Why have my data relationships stopped working?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio

I've been using Marketing Cloud (in conjunction with Sales Cloud) for a few years now, we set up some Data Relationships in Email Studio to allow us to create Filtered Data Extensions based on our Synchronised Data Extensions.

Up until January, they have stopped working, what I mean by this is that the filters don't return any records anymore. The data structure not as the data changed so not sure why its not returning any data. It appears NONE of the data relationships are working no longer.

I have verified the criteria has got records by doing the exact same criteria in a SQL statement, which returned records in one instead of a filter.

Can anyone explain why this could be and how I could resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried contacting support?

Comment: Yep, they simply said it was a criteria issue.. without even looking at the data or the relationship.